# Running tests using selenium standalone server failing with error in AbstractHttpCommandCodec class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testim.io

I am running a test in Selenium grid from my docker which is written in Testim (using testimony-cli) and getting the below error:

```
23:22:57.146 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$1] - Unable to execute request: POST /session/dc6c27f14e84100e65a65b769f0690c4/moveto
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.2.2-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_282'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
23:22:57.146 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$1] - org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST /session/dc6c27f14e84100e65a65b769f0690c4/moveto
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.2.2-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_282'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.decode(AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:293)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.decode(AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.ProtocolConverter.execute(ProtocolConverter.java:123)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.ProtocolConvertingSession.execute(ProtocolConvertingSession.java:75)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.SessionSlot.execute(SessionSlot.java:127)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode.executeWebDriverCommand(LocalNode.java:470)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.ForwardWebDriverCommand.execute(ForwardWebDriverCommand.java:35)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$PredicatedRoute.handle(Route.java:373)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute(SpanWrappedHttpHandler.java:86)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.Node.execute(Node.java:245)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.CombinedHandler.execute(CombinedHandler.java:59)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.RoutableHttpClientFactory$1.execute(RoutableHttpClientFactory.java:72)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.ReverseProxyHandler.execute(ReverseProxyHandler.java:92)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.router.HandleSession.execute(HandleSession.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$PredicatedRoute.handle(Route.java:373)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.router.Router.execute(Router.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.CheckOriginHeader.lambda$apply$0(CheckOriginHeader.java:66)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.CheckContentTypeHeader.lambda$apply$0(CheckContentTypeHeader.java:70)
at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.EnsureSpecCompliantResponseHeaders.lambda$apply$0(EnsureSpecCompliantResponseHeaders.java:34)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$NestedRoute.handle(Route.java:270)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.lambda$apply$0(AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.java:35)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0(ErrorFilter.java:44)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0(ErrorFilter.java:44)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
at org.openqa.selenium.netty.server.SeleniumHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(SeleniumHandler.java:44)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Details of the docker machine:

centos7:0.19
google chrome stable - 112.0.5615.49
chromedriver - 112.0.5615.49

I am starting the selenium server in headless mode:

`xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" java -jar selenium-server-4.8.0.jar standalone --host 0.0.0.0 --log-level FINE`

As you can see, I am using the latest version of Selenium Server, Chrome & Chromedriver.

**Does anyone know if anything obvious stands out that is causing this failure?**